# Adding graphics showing $\pm\Delta_{c^1}$, $\pm\Delta_{c^2}$, $\pm\Delta_{c^3}$ to a plot

Tags: projection

I have a ellipsoid equation given bellow. I want to find $\pm\Delta_{c^1}$, $\pm\Delta_{c^2}$, $\pm\Delta_{c^3}$ around the point $(81.32, 10.62, 17.17)$

```
Show[
  ContourPlot3D[
    425182.22 + 64.14985 c1^2 + 2.176 c2^2 + 
    c2 (-1.013*10^-13 - 0.006 c3) + 
    c1 (-10442.15 - 0.567c2 + 0.863846077 c3) - 
    70.3549202 c3 + 0.0052366 c3^2 == 1, 
    {c1,81,81.7}, {c2,9,12},{c3,-5,40},
    AxesLabel -> {c1, c2, c3},
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.7]],
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 15], 
    Mesh-> None],
  Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.015], Point[{81.32, 10.62, 17.17}]}]]
```

Comment: The meaning of $\pm\Delta_{c^1}$, $\pm\Delta_{c^2}$, $\pm\Delta_{c^3}$ may be clear to you, but not to me. Definitions for these quantities are needed.

Comment: Sorry. Just leave that part. I asked something wrong. Leave that part. I only need the projection.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = 425182.22 + 64.14985 c1^2 + 2.176 c2^2 + 
   c2 (-1.013*10^-13 - 0.006 c3) + 
   c1 (-10442.15 - 0.567 c2 + 0.863846077 c3) - 70.3549202 c3 + 
   0.0052366 c3^2 - 1;

c = {c1, c2, c3};
(*Finding the center by finding the minimum of the quadratic function*)

center = c /. Solve[D[f, {c, 1}] == {0, 0, 0}, c][[1]];
x = {x1, x2, x3};
(*Finding the principal axes with  Eigensystem.*)
A = 1/2 D[f /. Thread[c -> x], {x, 2}] /(-f /. Thread[c -> center]);
{a, e} = Eigensystem[A];
paxes = 1/Sqrt[a] e;


contour = 
  ContourPlot3D[f == 0, {c1, 81, 81.7}, {c2, 9, 12}, {c3, -5, 40},
   PlotPoints -> 60,
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[.25],
   Mesh -> None
   ];

Show[
 contour,
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25], Blue, 
   Ellipsoid[center, Inverse[A]], PointSize[Large], 
   Point[center],
   Thick, Black, Opacity[1],
   Red, Line[{center, center + paxes[[1]]}],
   Green, Line[{center, center + paxes[[2]]}],
   Blue, Line[{center, center + paxes[[3]]}]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.